# how to write code blocks using maruku

Tags: ruby, maruku

how can i write code blocks in maruku 
for ruby,javascript

currently i am using technique. but my first line moving to left.

```
hash["test"] = "test"
hash.merge!("test" => "test")
h=HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
h.update(:test => "test")
```

{:lang=ruby html_use_syntax=true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/) is just a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) interpreter.

[To produce a code block in Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode), simply indent every line of the block by at least 4 spaces or 1 tab. For example, given this input:

```
This is a normal paragraph:

    This is a code block.
```

Markdown will generate:

```
<p>This is a normal paragraph:</p>

<pre><code>This is a code block.
</code></pre>
```

Comment: This fails if for me if I have more than 1 line of code to be put in a code block. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I add this answer because I ended up here searching for a solution to code blocks with Maruku using *Jekyll*. For anyone else in the same boat, use the Liquid tags for code blocks instead of the Markdown syntax:

```
{% highlight java %}  
System.out.println("Hello, Maruku.");  
{% endhighlight %}
```

Also see this question/answer: [Highlight with Jekyll and pygments doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761990/highlight-with-jekyll-and-pygments-doesnt-works)