# Highlight with Jekyll and pygments doesn't work

Tags: jekyll, pygments

I want to use [pygments](http://pygments.org/) with [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll)

I have the following code:

```
{% highlight java %}
NullPointerException at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap
{% endhighlight %}
```

When I generate my site with `jekyll --pygments`, the html result is:

```
<div>
  <pre><code class="java">NullPointerException at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap</code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

In this html output there aren't the expected `<span class="n">` or `<span class="s2">` tags, and the code is not highlighted.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: May be a silly question, but rather than testing with an exception message, what happens if you try some actual java code?

Comment: yes, I tried with java code and also ruby code and got the same behaviour

Comment: Do you have pygments properly installed?

Comment: I guess, the 'sudo easy_install Pygments' worked fine, how to be sure it's installed properly?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to have the css generated to highlight.

```
$ pygmentize -S default -f html > css/pygments/default.css
```

Comment: +10 - this should really be more prominent (existing?) in the Jekyll docs

Comment: Note that you'll also have to tell your Jekyll template(s) to pick up the new CSS file -- in my case, by editing _layouts/default.html (Jekyll bootstrap).

Comment: I just added some notes to the [jekyll install wiki](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Install) about how to actually use Pygments after you have it installed. Hopefully, it'll clear things up.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you must first install pygment:  `pip install Pygment`.

Comment: `$ pip install Pygment`
`Collecting Pygment`
  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pygment (from versions: )`
`No matching distribution found for Pygment`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to installing pygments separately and generating the CSS, one can directly pull the CSS from the Jekyllrb documentation [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#stylesheets-for-syntax-highlighting)

The direct link extracted from the documentation I mentioned above is here: https://github.com/mojombo/tpw/blob/master/css/syntax.css

(It's the authors official version on GitHub)

The file is called syntax.css, drop it into your css folder, and create a relative link to the stylesheet in the header of any/all files to enable syntax highlighting.

This can be done as such for example, I placed it in `head.html` or `css.html` where I have all the relative links, it's in the `_include` folder so it gets included in all layouts that uses it:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/syntax.css">`

You might also need to add this to your `_config.yml`:

`highlighter: pygments`

Tested to work on Jekyll and also on GitHub Pages (which is special as it only allows a very limited set of plugins)

A related SO question that also assisted me in arriving to the right solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652490/do-i-need-to-generate-a-css-file-from-pygments-for-my-jekyll-blog-to-enable-col). I was also puzzled by why my code still wasn't highlighted in a template I'm porting over even after adding the line in `_config.yml`. The reason it just works on the auto-generated Jekyll site when doing `jekyll new test-site` is because the generated template already includes the SASS (`.scss`) for syntax-highlighting (in the `_sass` directory) which helps generate it all into one `main.css`.