# Fenced code block not highlighted properly

Tags: css, jekyll, syntax-highlighting, kramdown, rouge

In Jekyll, when I set the Markdown converter to kramdown and `bundle exec jekyll serve`, this fenced code block

````
```javascript
function hey(name) {
    return 'Hey ' + name;
}

console.log(hey('Brienna'));
```
````

renders like this:
[image: kramdown]

This happens no matter what I do. I've tried setting the `input: GFM` option, but it doesn't make a difference whether or not it's included.

However, when I set the Markdown converter to Redcarpet, the same code block renders like this:
[image: 1 appearance]

This is what I want to see! But I don't want to use Redcarpet. I want to use kramdown.

As you can see from the rendered HTML below, the code block gets highlighted. I'm using a CSS stylesheet for Pygments, which Rouge is supposed to be able to work with. I noticed that the `div`'s class changed between Markdown converters. With kramdown, its class is `.highlighter-rouge`, whereas with Redcarpet, its class is just `highlight`. Do I need to manually modify the CSS if switching between Markdown converters?

Kramdown:

[image: kramdown elements]

Redcarpet:

[image: 1 elements]

Comment: Are you hosting this on GitHub pages?

Comment: Yes, I am, @approxiblue. My issue above arises when I serve locally.

Answer (score 1):

Your Pygments CSS file looks like this:

```css
.highlight { font-size: 13px; }
div.highlight, div.highlight code, div.highlight pre  { background: #29281e; }
div.highlight code { padding: 0; }
div.highlight .c { color: #75715e } /* Comment */
```

In the Kramdown output, the `.highlight` block is no longer a `<div>`, so simply removing all "div" instances from the CSS would restore syntax highlighting.

Bonus: without specifically targeting `<div>`, your CSS now works with output of both Markdown processors.

---

For the fenced code blocks to work in Kramdown, you need to turn on [recognition of GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#kramdown):

```yaml
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Note that Jekyll reads `_config.yml` only once at execution time. You need to restart `jekyll serve` for further changes to apply.

Comment: Your suggestion to remove all 'div' instances form the CSS restores syntax highlighting. More needs to be done to get the same margins, padding, etc. I wasn't aware I had to manually edit the stylesheet -- is this a normal part of the process of switching between markdown converters?

Comment: I think it depends. The Pygments stylesheets are [generated by code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14989819), which means they might differ slightly between versions. The CSS someone [generated and archived here, for example](https://github.com/iwootten/jekyll-syntax), don't have the div selectors. Your stylesheet does, and it came from a theme, and I'm not sure where or how the author got it.

Comment: Still, the CSS remains mostly similar, selectors like `.kd`, `.nx`, `.p`, etc should be unchanged, so a few tweaks here and there would be enough. If you want to, you could also use pygmentize to generate a new theme CSS.