# Jekyll code in jekyll

Tags: html, ruby, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I'm creating a bird's eye view tutorial for Jekyll, to be hosted on Github pages (on my blog that runs on Jekyll). So, I want to put some code there. If I put the following:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if post.categories contains '<categoryname>' %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h2>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

(all lines after tabspaces), it doesn't render as code, rather, it executes. How do I stop it from executing and render it as code?

Comment: Have a look at the `Code snippet highlighting` section on http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761990/highlight-with-jekyll-and-pygments-doesnt-works

Comment: I tried this too. How do I highlight jekyll? Works on html though

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `{%...%}` syntax used by Jekyll is part of the [Liquid templating engine](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics). To escape these tags, and so show them literally, you should use the [`raw` tag](http://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/theme-tags#raw).

You will probably want to combine this with the markdown syntax for code blocks. With Redcarpet you can use the triple backtick syntax. It doesn’t matter if you put the backticks inside the `raw` tags or the other way round:

````
{%raw%}
```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if post.categories contains '<categoryname>' %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h2>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```
{%endraw%}
````

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your code in backticks:

(tested with redcarpet markdown engine)

````
```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if post.categories contains '<categoryname>' %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h2>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```
````

Comment: The markdown engine is specified in your _config.yml. I have this line in mine: markdown: redcarpet

Comment: Ah! I'm using `rdiscount`. So is it a problem with the engine @zeis?

Comment: Different engines may use different markers for code blocks.

Comment: Any idea which marker this might use. 
Tabs work in most cases

Comment: I don't use rdiscount, anyway try this: {% highlight html %} YOUR CODE HERE {% endhighlight %} this should work with pygments enabled, but I've not tested it.

Comment: Thank you! But the other answer addressed my exact issue. +10 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three options exist, taht you can use to format code in Jekyll:

1. *highlight* - Jekyll has built in

```
{% highlight java %}
ValidationResult validationResult = NetLicensing.LicenseeService.validate(context, licenseeNumber);
{% endhighlight %}
```

example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Labs64/netlicensing.io/gh-pages/_drafts/2010-09-16-post-template.md (see *Syntax highlighting* section)

2. *backtick* - GitHub style

````
```java
ValidationResult validationResult = NetLicensing.LicenseeService.validate(context, licenseeNumber);
```
````

3. HTML pre/code - HTML can be included in markdown as well

`<pre><code>
ValidationResult validationResult = NetLicensing.LicenseeService.validate(context, licenseeNumber);
<code/></pre>`